# Android / Gradle: Is it possible to create several drawable directories in my source-set?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In my module, I have created a resources directory under the source-set `main` (`app/src/main/<my-resources-dir>`). In which I have created several directories (one for each feature of my application), each containing a `drawable` directory.

However, I can't use the files within these `drawable` folders in my layouts for example. Android Studio says that it can't "resolve symbol @drawable/logo_black` *e.g.*

Is it possible to make it work? I'd really want to separate my drawables files in several drawable directories (kind of bundles tree structure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Declaring each bundle directory as a resources folder in the app-level Gradle build file works.

For example, considering the following bundle directory: `<module>/src/<sources_set>/<bundle>/` (*e.g.:* `app/src/main/account/`), we can edit the manifest file (`<same_module>/build.gradle`) like this:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = [
                    'src/main/account',
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it that way, You only can create different folders for different screen sizes. That's how Android is taking advantage of different folders. And I don't think if you can do anything about it, but using naming conventions. I always name my drawables related to what they're going to do and where they're going to be.